# Apply altogether the multiple implementations or condition of an interface

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have an interface Calculate which has a single method calculate(List priceList)
`public interface Calculate { public List<Double> calculate(List<Double> priceList); }`

Each implementation of this interface will do some calculation and check for some conditions on the priceList values and if the condition satisfies on that price value, then it will return list of the satisfying values from the priceList as the output.

Example.

```
`public class CalculateImpl1 implements Calculate { 
       @Override
       public List<Double> calculate(List<Double> priceList) { 
        List<Double> result = new AL();
        loop the priceList
       if(condition1 satisfies on priceList value) { 
         result.add(value); 
       } 
      return result;
    } 
  }

  public class CalculateImpl2 implements Calculate { 
       @Override
       public List<Double> calculate(List<Double> priceList) { 
        List<Double> result = new AL();
        loop the priceList
       if(condition2 satisfies on priceList value) { 
         result.add(value); 
       } 
      return result;
    } 
  }`
```

Let say there is class which has the priceList data and I can apply calculation to that priceList using any of the Calculate interface implementation.

Question: How to achieve if I want to apply all the calculation(CalculateImp1/condition1, CalculateImpl2/condition2....) to the priceList at the same time, means the priceList should satisfy all the conditions and get the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what predicate used for:

```
public class CalculateImpl implements Calculate { 
     @Override
     public List<Double> calculate(List<Double> priceList, Predicate<Double> filter) { 
         priceList.stream().filter(filter).collect(Collectors.toList());
    } 
}
```

Then use it:

```
Calculate calc = new CalculateImpl();
Predicate<Double> pre1 = d -> {condition1}; 
// Eg: Predicate<Double> pre1 = d -> d > 100; (filter price whose values greater than 100)
List<Double> list1 = calc.calculate(priceLIst, pre1);
```

To combine conditions:

```
Predicate<Double> pre2 = d -> {condition2};
List<Double> list2 = calc.calculate(priceList, pre1.and(pre2));
```

To use `or` condition:

```
Predicate<Double> pre2 = d -> {condition2};
List<Double> list2 = calc.calculate(priceList, pre1.or(pre2));
```